# How to run Acceleo from generated java launcher class

Tags: java, eclipse, acceleo

Can anyone tell me how to run Acceleo from generated java launcher class ? That is, when I add [comment @main/] in my .mtl class, a new java class is generated. And now, Instead of using .mtl file to start the generation, I want to use the main method in this Java class to to the same work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this generated class is what acceleo uses to launch your generation.

You can create an acceleo launch configuration, and take a look at the second tab, it displays the java command line that is equivalent to this launch config.